# Integrating Relay with React native

Tags: react-native, graphql, relay

I want to integrate relay with react native.
I am getting following error:
getBabelRelayPlugin is not defined while processing preset

I used following steps to integrate react native with relay
1.Back up your project.
2. Make sure you have your GraphQL server ready and your schema.json at hand too. For more details about the latter two visit the React-Relay project page.
Ensure that you’re using `npm` version 3 or greater.
3.If React Native's packager (`react-native start`) is running somewhere in the background, you should stop it now.
4.Run: watchman watch-del-all

5.Delete the `./node_modules` directory from your project.
6.Edit your `package.json` file, make sure it has the following:
    "dependencies": {
      "react": "^0.14.7",
      "react-native": "facebook/react-native",
      "react-relay": "^0.7.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel-core": "^6.6.4", 
      "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.4.0",
      "babel-relay-plugin": "^0.7.3"
    }
Babel version is especially important. Make sure that your project uses babel 6.5 or later, we need it for the passPerPreset feature in .babelrc file.
7.Create a new file `.babelrc` and place it in your project's directory:
    {
      "presets": [
        "./scripts/babelRelayPlugin",
        "react-native"
      ],
      "passPerPreset": true
    }
8.Create a new file in your project's directory called `babelRelayPlugin.js` with the following content:
    const getBabelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin');
    const schema = require('./schema.json');

```
module.exports = { plugins: [getBabelRelayPlugin(schema.data)] };
```

9Copy your `schema.json` file to the project's directory too.
10.Run: npm install

Comment: Have you correctly implemented babelRelayPlugin? Here you can find more info
https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-babel-plugin.html#content